# Postman returns 200ok and not 201 created

Tags: postman

We have created scripted rest API with post method which creates records in the table . On triggering API from postman ,it returns 200 ok and not 201 created .How do we get 201 Created and not 200Ok

Comment: Please show some code from your method.

Comment: An API will not magically return 201 unless it is coded to do so. It will always default to 200 for a successful response.

Comment: Postman is the tool you're using to exercise your API. It's your API that is choosing to return 200 or 201. To focus on postman seems entirely wrong.

Comment: @MladenSavić  -- Hi Mladen , my code looks something like this ,

Comment: @MladenSavić  -- Hi Mladen , my code looks something like this ,          
  (function process(/*RESTAPIRequest*/ request, /*RESTAPIResponse*/ response) {
     var jsonString = request.body.dataString; 
  var parser = new JSONParser();
  var parsed = parser.parse(jsonString);  
  var rel = new GlideRecord ('u_resource_facing_services');
   rel.initialize();
    rel.u_external_key_id = parsed.u_external_label;
 rel.insert(); 
return{
   "service_instance_id" : number,
   "Message" : "Service Instance created successfully"
    }; 
 
})(request, response);

Comment: Don't post code in comments. [edit] your question and paste the code there. (Whilst doing this, highlight all of the code and hit the `{}` button as well and you'll see in the preview/when you resubmit your question that it *looks like code too*). Whilst you're doing this, you may want to consider whether you want to be talking about postman so much and, at the least, add a tag for *whatever language that code is in*.